# How can i pass parameter from javascript to generic handler?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I called generic handler (ashx) from javascript code as given below;

```
var xmlHttpReq = createXMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttpReq.open("GET", "hndlrCars.ashx, false);
            xmlHttpReq.send(null);
            xmlText = xmlHttpReq.responseText;
```

But i have to pass parameter (dropdown selectedvalue) from .aspx to generic handler's "ProcessRequest" method.How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass it as a query string parameter:

```
var value = ...
xmlHttpReq.open('GET', 'hndlrCars.ashx?value=' + encodeURIComponent(value), false);
```

And inside the handler retrieve it from the request:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string value = context.Request["value"];
    ...
}
```